# Return the largest k-th number, accounting for multiplicity (duplicates)

Tags: excel, ranking, vba

Is there some manual I *didn't* read that shows the VBA way to return the k-th largest number from a range - ignoring duplicates? I have no idea why this is not just the default way the worksheet function `RANK` works.... This is part of an integer solver problem, which takes ages to run as it is, and this function will be called a large number of times - I don't want to makes things slower than they need to be.

I thought about using the unique-key facility of a collection (load my range into a collection, let the collection throw away the duplicates via `key` then use `RANK`, or `LARGE` or whatever)...but that seemed like overkill.

Below is an obvious recursive method...but with all those references to worksheet functions, etc, I think I'm missing some really obvious VBA/Excel function/functionality? This just seems too tragic for such a simple task, is there a "better" way to do this, where better = "not using recursive worksheet function calls - or creating, filling, copying, destroying collections on each function call"?

```
Public Function getRank(ByRef r As range, k As Integer) As Double

If (k < 1) Then Exit Function

If (k = 1) Then
    getRank = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(r)
    Exit Function
End If

getRank = Application.WorksheetFunction.Large(r, Application.WorksheetFunction. _
CountIf(r, ">=" & getRank(r, k - 1)) + 1)

End Function
```

My `r` is a column with this data in it, as a test.

```
-100%
50%
-100%
-100%
-100%
-100%
-200%
-100%
-200%
-100%
-200%
-100%
-200%
-200%
-100%
-100%
60%
-200%
-100%
50%
-200%
-200%
-200%
60%
60%
-100%
-200%
-100%
-100%
-200%
-200%
60%
60%
-200%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To gain optimal speed, consider separating the functionality into two parts:

1. an event macro
2. a simple lookup **UDF**

The event macro would create a public static array from the column values, discarding duplicates and sorting the uniques.  The macro would only run initially and when the column changes.

The **UDF** then only needs to index into the created array based on the index in its header.

Comment: Thanks. I could try that. I have multiple columns that need to be "evaluated" (will change) at each "pass" of the Solver - also not sure how event macro will interlove with Solver...But will give it a go. More worrying is the fact that there actually appears not to be a built-in way to do this in Excel...I assumed I was just missing something obvious. Ta